# vba ADOBE.recordset filter/find

Tags: vba, excel

I have a ADOBE.Recordset in Excel VBA returned from a query to database. How should I find a certain record in this set that fits certain criteria? Below is the code. Could anyone fill in the " 'print out the name of one person whose age is i" part for me? Thanks in advance!

```
Dim rs As ADOBE.Recordset
q = "select name, age from people where country = 'US'"
Set rs = conn.Execute(q) 'conn is an ADOBE.Connection
For i = 30 To 40
    'print out the name of one person whose age is i 
Next i
```

**Update 1:**
Thanks KazJaw! I think your solutions should work. However, I am looking for a cleaner solution -

1. I don't want to save the query results into a sheet. I'd prefer them in memeory.
2. Is there a .Find or .Search function I can use so that I don't need to implement the search with a loop (as you did in the Second Solution)?

Maybe I am being greedy here, but ideally, I'd like something like this:

```
Dim rs As ADOBE.Recordset
q = "select name, age from people where country = 'US'"
Set rs = conn.Execute(q) 'conn is an ADOBE.Connection
For i = 30 To 40
    name = rs.Find("age = i")!name 'this line is where I am not sure how to achieve 
    MsgBox name & "'s age is " & i 
Next i
```

Apologies for the formatting. I am new to the site, not sure how to properly indent the two lines in the For loop.

**Update 2:**

Yes KazJaw, other problem rises. ".Find" requires rs to be able to scrolled back, which requires its lockType to be set to adLockOptimistic. Haven't figured out how yet. Will post if I do.

**Solution:**
The Key is to use rs.Open instead of conn.Execute and to set CursorType.

```
Dim rs As ADOBE.Recordset
q = "select name, age from people where country = 'US' Order By i"
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open Source:=q, CursorType:=adOpenStatic,  ActiveConnection:=ThisWorkbook.conn 'conn is an ADOBE.Connection      
For i = 30 To 40
    name = rs.Find("age = i")!name 'this line is where I am not sure how to achieve 
    MsgBox name & "'s age is " & i 
Next i
```

Comment: filter your query before getting the recordset - take advantage of the `where` clause. so `q = "select name, age from people where country = 'US' and age > 10"`

Comment: Thanks mehows! This is exact what I am doing right now. However, doing this way would generate multiple queries (11 queries in the sample code I posted) to the database and thus make the application slow. Since my dataset is not very large in my case, I'd like to query out all US people into a Recordset in one query and then further filter it in memory when I need to use a particular record in it.

Comment: smaller recordset with what you want is still going to be more efficient than filtering a big one.

Comment: where you want to print it out? to continuous excel range? non-continuous range? immediate window?

Comment: Anywhere is fine. Let's say show it on MsgBox. I just need to get the "name".

Comment: see edit of my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First solution,** without looping, you could do it in this way but you need to stick to @mehow suggestion where `age condition` should be implemented in SQL query.

```
'return all results as of cell A2, direction down+right, in activesheet
ActiveSheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
```

**Second solution,** with looping, instead of your `For i...Next` loop try below solution.

```
Dim lRow as long
lRow=2
With rs
    Do Until .EOF
        'return only those which age equals to i
        'if implemented in SQL query then you could get rid of if statement below
        if .Fields(1).Value = i then
            Cells(lRow, 1) = .Fields(1).Value
            Cells(lRow, 2) = .Fields(2).Value
        .MoveNext
        lRow = lRow + 1
        end if
    Loop
End With
```

**Third solution.** If you really need to use `.Find method` then do it in this way:

```
'...your loop here

rs.Find "age = " & i
name = rs(0)
MsgBox name & "'s age is " & i 

'... rest of your code here
```

Unfortunately, I'm not sure if it will work. I think you will need to sort your results by age within SQL code. If not I expect some of the ages can be omit. Some other problems could arise. Therefore try with other solutions.